# Memory leak in C program, can't see where to free memory

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am writing a C program to generate Keys and test them in an encryption function.  However since I have NEVER written a C program before, and I'm completely unused to having manage memory manually, I have run into a problem.  I have a memory leak and to be honest, I don't know how to solve it. I understand I need to release the memory at some point but can't until I've run through all keys and I run out of memory before I get through all of them.  Writing the program in a different language is NOT an option so please do not suggest that.  The code that is leaking is shown below, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I know i haven't called a free function to free the memory.  I don't see where I can put it because I need the memory until i run through all keys.  Putting it outside the loops doesn't solve the problem because the leak occurs inside the loops

2nd EDIT:  Posted the full program.  I do not have the option of using data structures (i.e. the bool arrays) other than those shown because of how the DES encrypt function(which I did not write) works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "des.h"

void dec2bin(bool *testaRR, bool *to_return, int convert);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

// insert code here...
bool testKey[56] = {
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1
};
bool testKey2[56] = {//intuitive key reversed for testing
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
     1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0
};
 bool output[64];

 bool input[64] = {//the reverse of below...  DES bits are numbered left to right, in order of least to most significant so we must enter the bit values in reverse.
     //forexample the binary vale of N is 01001110 but below is displayed as 01110010
 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,//1
 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,//0
 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,//C
 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,//E
 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,//S
 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,//T
 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0,//E
 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0 //N
 };
 int y = sizeof(input);
 printf("(Input MSG: ");
 for (int i = y-4; i >= 0; i-=4)
 printf("%X", input[i]+2*input[i+1]+4*input[i+2]+8*input[i+3]);//this is the conversion to    hex code
 printf(")\n");

/*
 use char[] to store the key as set of 
 */
/*bool input[64] = {//this is the given plaintext message in the intuitive order (opposite of what it is)   
    0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0,//N
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,//E

    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0,//T
    0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1,//S
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1,//E
    0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,//C
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,//0
    0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1 //1
};


int y = sizeof(input);
printf("(Input MSG: ");
for (int j = 0; j < y; j+=4)
    printf("%X", input[j+3]+2*input[j+2]+4*input[j+1]+8*input[j]);//this is the conversion to hex code
printf(")\n");*/
bool test [8];
bool returned[8];
char keyphrase [8];
keyphrase[7] = 0;

for(int start = 65; start<=90; start++)
{
     //dec2bin(test, returned, start);
 keyphrase[0] = start;
    for(int two = 65; two<=90; two++){
        keyphrase[1]=two;
        for(int three = 65; three<=90; three++){
            keyphrase[2]=three;
            for(int four = 65; four<=90; four++){
                keyphrase[3]=four;
                for(int five = 65;five<=90;five++){
                    keyphrase[4]=five;
                    for( int six = 65; six <=90; six++){
                        keyphrase[5]=six;
                        for(int seven = 65; seven <=90; seven++){
                            keyphrase[6]=seven;
                            printf("%s \n", keyphrase);
                        }

                            }}
                        }
                    }
                }
 //once i fix the memory leak I will be calling the EncryptDes Function here and checking the outputblk agains the given cipher text
}
free(keyphrase);

int k = sizeof(testKey);
printf("(Test Key: ");
for (int z = 0; z < k; z+=7)
    printf("%d", testKey[z+7]+2*testKey[z+6]+4*testKey[z+5]+8*testKey[z+4]+16*testKey[z+3]+32*testKey[z+2]+64*testKey[z+1]+ 128*testKey[z]);//this is the conversion to hex code
printf(")\n");

//loop on the key (starting at
EncryptDES(testKey, output, input, 0);
int x = sizeof(output);
printf("(Output MSG: ");
for (int i = 0; i < x; i+=4)
    printf("%X", output[i+3]+2*output[i+2]+4*output[i+1]+8*output[i]);//this is the conversion to hex code
printf(")\n");


return 0;
}
void dec2bin (bool *testaRR, bool *to_return, int convert)

{
 printf("%d : ", convert);
 printf("%c", convert);
 printf("\n ");

//bool testaRR [8];
for(int st = 0; st<8; st++){
    testaRR[st] = convert%2;
    to_return[7-st] = testaRR[st];
    //printf("%d :", 7-st);
   //printf(" %d spot ", st);
    convert = convert/2;
    //testaRR stores the arrays in one direction
    //to_return stores them in the other
    //Example:
    //65 = 01000001 testaRR least significant on the far right (m0st sig is in index 7)better for storage and keeping track of where the bits actually are in binary
    //65 = 10000010 to_return least significant on the far left (same as DES) (most significant bit is index 0) good for printing to screen
}
```

Comment: on a side note, there is no need to cast the return value of malloc() in C, because there is an implicit conversion from void* to any other pointer type (in C++ this does not apply).  Casting it anyway will only shut up the compiler in case you don't have the malloc prototype in scope (read: in case you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>`), resulting in undefined behaviour

Comment: I don't understand why you believe you have a memory leak in the first place. There's no memory leak inside the loops. I think what you are calling a "memory leak" is some completely different error.

Comment: while its looping my computer runs out of memory…
and it does not when I'm not running the loops

Comment: How do you know that "your computer runs out of memory"?

Comment: because I'm watching the available memory go down from over 4 free GB to about 5 MB… I use iStatPro to monitor

Comment: Since the program you posted -- once it is fixed to null terminate the buffer as described in other answers -- does not allocate more than eight bytes of memory, it seems unlikely that this is the cause of you running out of memory, if in fact you are.  If that's the case then the problem is somewhere else in the program, or there's something that you're not telling us. **Post a small program that clearly reproduces the problem**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real problem is the use of `printf`. You did not NULL terminate `keyphrase`, so every time you `printf` you overflow.

Also, to avoid the memory leak, simply replace `char *keyphrase = (char *)malloc(7);` with `char keyphrase[8];`.

Comment: I initially tried just declaring char key phrase[7] but that too caused a memory leak.

Comment: Like I said, the real problem is the `printf` call.

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: `char keyphrase[7]` did _not_ cause a memory leak.

Comment: @Jake: The argument to `printf` needs to be null terminated. You did not NULL terminate `keyphrase`. This is why your program does not work.

Comment: nit: The zero char is usually written NUL with one ell, to distinguish it from the NULL pointer constant.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need dynamic memory management here.

Start with

```
char keyphrase[8];
keyphrase[7]=0;
```

instead of your `malloc` and you will be good to go. Your highest array index is 7 (the terminating `NUL`), and hence you need an array of 8 items (0..7).

If you really want to use `malloc`, simply a `free()` at the end will be fine, but you need to `malloc` 8 characters and set `keyphrase[7]` to 0 to do the terminating `NUL` still.

Here's a tested version that works:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* compile with gcc -Wall -std=c99 keyphrase.c -o keyphrase */

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  char keyphrase[8];
  keyphrase[7] = 0;
  for (int start = 65; start <= 90; start++)
    {
      //dec2bin(test, returned, start);
      keyphrase[0] = start;
      for (int two = 65; two <= 90; two++)
        {
          keyphrase[1] = two;
          for (int three = 65; three <= 90; three++)
            {
              keyphrase[2] = three;
              for (int four = 65; four <= 90; four++)
                {
                  keyphrase[3] = four;
                  for (int five = 65; five <= 90; five++)
                    {
                      keyphrase[4] = five;
                      for (int six = 65; six <= 90; six++)
                        {
                          keyphrase[5] = six;
                          for (int seven = 65; seven <= 90; seven++)
                            {
                              keyphrase[6] = seven;
                              printf ("%s \n", keyphrase);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this add over my answer?

Comment: Just attempted this but the program ate all my memory again.  Thanks though

Comment: @DeadMG your answer wasn't there when I started typing.

Comment: @Jake - perhaps the problem is that you are missing the `#include` and thus it's using the wrong prototype for `printf`. I've re-indented it and made the changes I was suggesting, and it runs just fine for me.

Comment: I had the #includes in my program, i just included the snippet I was having issues with.  I tried this method but unfortunately didn't solve it on my end.  I will attempt DeadMG's answer.  Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `malloc` on the first line but I don't see a single `free` to release what you allocated. After all the loops are completed (i.e. usage of the allocated data is complete) you must call `free(keyphrase);`

Comment: I realize that.  But where does the free go?  every time I put the statement in, it throws errors

Comment: Free is the least of the problem here.

Comment: @Jake: Why do you assign integer values to a char in a loop?

Comment: because i have to convert from Ascii to binary for the program I am writing.  i.e.  I store ascii numerical values for characters so that I can pull the integer out and convert it to its binary value

Comment: You just need simple `if` statements, you approach is very wrong; just looking at the number of for loops says this. Read a good book on C.

Comment: yea i don't think I have time to read a C book by the time this needs to be done but thanks for the advice

Comment: years later, I should add this was a program to brute force a key used to secure data (grad school project not hacking) so the loops were necessary for brute forcing

Answer (score 1):

New answer as the program has been modified.

You say your program is using all memory *'because I'm watching the available memory go down from over 4 free GB to about 5 MB'*.

I'm guessing the answer is not the loops but these lines:

```
//loop on the key (starting at
EncryptDES(testKey, output, input, 0);
int x = sizeof(output);
```

We can't see the source to or declaration of *EncryptDES*, but you aren't passing a length to it. If `0` is meant to be the length, this would explain it.

The next line however suggests that `output` is meant to be an array of 64 bytes (rather than 2 strings). But `EncryptDES` would have no way of knowing this.

I suggest you run the whole thing under `valgrind` to find out what is happening.

Comment: i think figured it out.  Apparently it was happening because i was trying to print all generated keys to the screen.   I didn't realize that printf was such a resource hog.  once i stopped trying to print every key my issue disappeared.  Thanks for the help, though!